# Can not to store form data into database PHP (instead i got success message )

Tags: php, database, forms, connection, submit

Hi every one please help me I have problem with my code . I want to store my form data into database but can not instead i got success message ( thank you for your comment)
Please help me

My form code is this

**com_form.php**

```
<form method='post'>
  Name: <input type='text' name='name' id='name' /><br />

  Email: <input type='text' name='email' id='email' /><br />

  Comment:<br />
  <textarea name='comment' id='comment'></textarea><br />

  <input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<? echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' />

  <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
</form>
```

and PHP code is this

**manage_com.php**

```
    <?
if( $_POST )
{
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","dbname");
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

  $sql="SELECT name,email,comment FROM comments ";
  $retval=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


  $users_name = $_POST['name'];
  $users_email = $_POST['email'];
  $users_comment = $_POST['comment'];

  $users_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['$users_name']);
  $users_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['$users_email']);
  $users_comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['$users_comment']);

  $articleid = $_GET['id'];
  if( ! is_numeric($articleid) )
    die('invalid article id');

  $query = "
  INSERT INTO `pricemom_comment`.`comments` (`id`, `name`, `email`,
        `comment`, `post_date`, `articleid`) VALUES (NULL, '$users_name',
        '$users_email', '$users_comment',
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$articleid');";

  mysqli_query($con,$query);

  echo "<h2>Thank you for your Comment!</h2>";

  mysqli_close($con);
}
?>
```

page where i want to show form
**page1.php**

```
<? include("manage_com.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>page1 created by Afzal</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <img src="nature.jpg" alt="beautifull nature image" style="width:700px; align:center;height:200px;">
    <h2>page1 created by Afzal</h2>
    <p style="width:700px;">order to display comments on a page, we first need to know what comments to show. When we setup our site we created two pages, and each page was assigned a unique id number. This ID number will be used to gather comments for that specific page. For example, when the user is on page 1, we'll select all of the comments in the database assigned to page "1".</p>

     <p style="width:700px;"> Now that we have our sample SQL query, we can use it to create the php code that will print all comments on a page. Below is the example code that we created. If you're not familiar with php, any line that begins with a // is a comment, and comments are used by developers to document their code. In our example, we have quite a few comments to help explain what the code is doing, but keep in mind that most scripts do not have as many comments.</p>

      <?php

include("com_form.php");
       ?>
  </body>

</html>
```

please fix my problem . where i make mistakes

**NOTE: I got success message ( thank you for you comment) but comment not store in my database**

Comment: `mysqli_query($con,$query);`   What to do if it fails for any reason? Add some error reporting

Answer (score 0):

Your echo statement display success no matter what happend.
Perform a query and check for error:

```
  if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
  {
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con)); die;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is connected with wrong sql request. You try to insert NUll value for `id` field.